# How to dump HTTP request headers + source ip of the client in Nginx?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, containers

Trying to troubleshoot Nginx deployed as a container. Is it possible to dump request info back to requester via webpage ?

For example, instead of standard "Welcome to Nginx!" page, could I get list of request headers and source ip of the client ?

Thank you !

[image: Welcome to NGINX]

Comment: you can if you write an application for it. you publish that in your nginx container and that will print out all the information you instruct it to.

Comment: Usually one can include that information in the [access log format](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/nginx-0.26.1/docs/user-guide/nginx-configuration/log-format.md#log-format), for _debugging_. Since you asked in a `kubernetes` tag, it's also *super painless* to deploy an "echo" service in the cluster for debugging requests, too, as nginx isn't really the right tool for doing dynamic content

Comment: @Andy Did those comments solved your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Found image build specially for that purpose : **gcr.io/google_containers/echoserver:1.4**

```
kubectl run echoserver --image=gcr.io/google_containers/echoserver:1.4 --port=8080

vagrant@master-1:~$ curl 172.16.97.199:8080
CLIENT VALUES:
client_address=172.16.39.0
command=GET
real path=/
query=nil
request_version=1.1
request_uri=http://172.16.97.199:8080/

SERVER VALUES:
server_version=nginx: 1.10.0 - lua: 10001

HEADERS RECEIVED:
accept=*/*
host=172.16.97.199:8080
user-agent=curl/7.58.0
BODY:
-no body in request-
```

Comment: How u got server ip? 
Which IP i should use to connect to server?
Sorry for basic question, just started exploring k8

Comment: It’s ether pod ip or LB ip. I explored both options